# Java Media Framework - MP3 Issues

Tags: java, mp3, jmf

Im using Windows 7 and can "Java Platform SE Binary" in my sound mixer but yet still no sound seems to play.

My code is:

```
import javax.media.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.MalformedURLExc;

public class SimpleAudioPlayer {
private Player audioPlayer = null;

public SimpleAudioPlayer(URL url) throws IOException, NoPlayerException, 
    CannotRealizeException {
    audioPlayer = Manager.createRealizedPlayer(url);
}

public SimpleAudioPlayer(File file) throws IOException, NoPlayerException, 
    CannotRealizeException {
    this(file.toURL());
}

public void play() {
    audioPlayer.start();
}

public void stop() {
    audioPlayer.stop();
    audioPlayer.close();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try{
        File audioFile = new File("/t.mp3");
        SimpleAudioPlayer player = new SimpleAudioPlayer(audioFile);

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("-> Playing file '" + 
                           audioFile.getAbsolutePath() + "'");
        System.out.println("   Press the Enter key to exit");
        player.play();

        // wait for the user to press Enter to proceed.
        System.in.read();
        System.out.println("-> Exiting");
        player.stop();
    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.exit(0);

}
}
```

I use the Windows Preformance JMF edition. The MP3 im trying to play works fine in VLC/WMP so it cant be the file.

The code also throws no exceptions or error when running, it just doesnt seem to play the sound.

Is there something im missing? Like pulling the sound card? E.g. taking over it so i can play sound out of it?

Im overall aim is to to a MP3 streaming service using RTP/RTSP so any links,advice or tuturiols would be help as im currelnt using [IBM JMF Tuturiol](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/tutorials/j-jmf/section2.html) and [Java Demo](http://java-demos.blogspot.co.uk/2012/11/java-code-to-play-mp3-file.html)

Please ask if any more information is needed!

UPDATE-

Downloaded [WAV FILE](http://freewavesamples.com/files/Yamaha-SY-35-Clarinet-C5.wav) and it seemed to play, how can i make MP3s play?

Added formats and tried this code and still the same issue:

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.media.Format;
import javax.media.Manager;
import javax.media.MediaLocator;
import javax.media.Player;
import javax.media.PlugInManager;
import javax.media.format.AudioFormat;

public class SimpleAudioPlayer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Format input1 = new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.MPEGLAYER3);
        Format input2 = new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.MPEG);

        Format output = new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.LINEAR);
        PlugInManager.addPlugIn(
            "com.sun.media.codec.audio.mp3.JavaDecoder",
            new Format[]{input1, input2},
            new Format[]{output},
            PlugInManager.CODEC
        );
        try {
            Player player = Manager.createPlayer(new MediaLocator(new File("/t.mp3").toURI().toURL()));
            player.start();
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

> Unable to handle format: mpeglayer3, 44100.0 Hz, 16-bit, Stereo, LittleEndian, Signed, 16000.0 frame rate, FrameSize=32768 bits
>   Failed to realize: com.sun.media.PlaybackEngine@62deaa2e
>   Error: Unable to realize com.sun.media.PlaybackEngine@62deaa2e

Thats the error!

Comment: I'm no expert on this, but I know that VLC comes with its own codecs (not OS ones). Did you try playing a `.wav` file to break down the problem?

Comment: Not yet will try that the now. I tried another MP3 and it gave a codec excpeiton but this just shows notihng. Ill try a .wav and get back to you in a few mins thanks

Comment: Your right, I will update my question

Comment: 1) *"The MP3 im trying to play works fine in VLC/WMP so it cant be the file."*  Most 'real world' media players go to ***extraordinary*** lengths to accept and handle any old rubbish, malformed files & do their best with them.  If you want to check the MP3, use a tool *designed to check MP3s.*
2) Try some of the [MP3s @ my site](http://pscode.org/media/#sound)  They definitely work with JMF.  3) It seems that code should pop a blocking GUI element between `player.play()` & `player.stop()`.  Simply starting a player would typically not block the following statements from being called.

Comment: Try playing the file with JMStudio which is an media player with JMF and don't try playing the files with VLC etc because JMF doesn't support all files and even if it supports a file then too there are problems like the codec for sound etc.

Comment: I tried: Dead_End.mp3  from your site and that didnt work..

Comment: If a file works with JMStudio it will definitely work in your application too. BTW I executed your code and it worked fine with the .mp3 file which I had already tested with JMStudio

Comment: Added error / to the question

Comment: Be sure to add @PersonName to inform them of a new comment.  *"FrameSize=32768 bits"*  Huh?  For stereo 16 bit, the frame size should be 32 bits.  Do you get *exactly* the same error with the MP3 from my site?

Comment: &Andrew Thompson can you recommend any links to start learning?

Comment: have you tried any solutions that works well...? @Lemex

Answer (score 1):

As I thought, it's a missing codec.

I think this is what you need: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/download-137625.html

Comment: Hardly.  JMF has an MP3 codec inbuilt.  If the OP can access `SimpleAudioPlayer` the codec should be installed.  If you add that codec to a standard Java app., then Java Sound will also decode MP3.